# Python: save 100 functions in the same file or in separate files?

Tags: python, function, code-organization

My main program calls 10 script files that serve as subprograms. Every script file calls about 20 of my 100 self-written functions. Is it advisable to write all the 100 functions in a large file or is it better to save every function as separate file?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. We don't take questions here that solicit opinion. My personal advice to you is to try things in various ways and see what feels most comfortable. See how much trouble it is to get around the code and understand what is going on, as you develop new features. See how it feels to *use* the code as a library; does the packaging make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation. If your functions can be grouped by some similarities or some properties, then you can group your functions in different files, modules and submodules. That's an architecture thing

Comment: If I place my functions in several files then I always must import them and adapt these import commands if I move a function into another file. If all functions are in one file then they can access each other. I consider my large function file just as a repository for usage in my scripts.

Comment: What you are talking about is called `monolith`, it's problem that it is hard to extend in future

Comment: why is it hard to extend? In my function file I can just add another function below the 100 previous functions.

Comment: That's because your project suits monolith pattern well, your case is simple, so you don't need to mind about archetype of your application